# How to get a variable inside of thread?

Tags: java, android, thread

I have a webservice receiving data and stores it in a String , how do I get this string Global variables doesnt work!
Im using a tradicional Thread: `new Thread() { public void run(){`

Comment: You are on StackOverflow in **Portuguese**, translate your question or go to the English version of StackOverflow.

Comment: Olá Daniel. Você poderia ter editado sua pergunta ao invés de criar uma nova como tradução. Mas tudo bem, só que tenho que fechá-la como duplicada da sua pergunta traduzida.